# How to join Campaign and campaign response in MS CRM 4.0

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-4

I tried to join Campaign and campaign response in SQL. We are migrating data to new CRM and all data we can get. Only information on witch campaign was witch response.

Something like

camapaing.id = id.x
x.id = campaignresponse.id

Answer (score 0):

CampaignResponse is an activity type, and the association back to Campaign is via the ActivityPointer.RegardingObjectId *which* will point you back to the campaign.

```
select cr.ActivityId, c.CampaignId from CampaignResponse cr 
inner join ActivityPointer ap on cr.ActivityId = ap.ActivityId
inner join Campaign c on c.CampaignId = ap.RegardingObjectId
```